# Integrate $x^2 e^{-x^2/2}$

Tags: calculus

> Is it possible to integrate $$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2/2}\, \mathrm dx$$
>   by hand?

The answer is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ My apologies if this does not meet the standards of this blog. I will delete it if requested.

Comment: Try to do it by parts twice...or even once.

Comment: I think you might be able to compare it to the gamma function?

Comment: ok, I am little rusty with calculus what do we set our u and dv at?

Comment: It seems that your answer is wrong: see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x^2+e^%28-x^2%2F2%29+from+x%3D0+to+infty

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By the Feynman trick we have:

$$I = \lim_{a\to 1}\int_0^{+\infty} -2\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a} e^{-(a x^2)/2}\right)\ \text{d}x = \lim_{a\to 1}-2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a}\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-(ax^2)/2}\ \text{d}x = \lim_{a\to 1} -2 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}$$

Hence

$$I = \lim_{a\to 1}-2\left(-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{3/2}\right)$$

And our integral is simply

$$I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$$

Which is the result of your integral.

Comment: Very nice trick!

Comment: @Babak Thank you! I really love that trick too, and finally I could use it :D

Comment: Nitpick: the LHS should not be $I(a)$ but $I$: it does not depend on $a$. Or you want to drop the $\lim_{a\to 1}$ there?

Comment: @ClementC. Whoops! Thanks!

Comment: @FourierTransform +1 Feynman's Trick comes to the rescue for all of the even powered moments.

Comment: Where did the limit $a\rightarrow 1$ go in the last expression in the first line?

Comment: @Lovsovs I forgot it, thanks! Going to edit

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $u = x$, $dv = xe^{-x^2/2}dx$

Comment: I do not see how you can integrate by parts here. Can you elaborate ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

No tricks, just the Gamma integral: Substituting $x = \sqrt{2t}$ gives
$$\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2/2} \,dx = \sqrt{2\vphantom{X}} \int_0^\infty t^{1/2} e^{-t} \,dt = \sqrt{2\vphantom{X}}\,\Gamma\Bigl(\frac32\Bigr) = \sqrt{\frac\pi2}.$$

Comment: Actually the Gamma function is a trick too :) But I give +1 because I love the Gamma function!

Comment: And how does one evaluate the Gamma function at half integers?  Using the functional relationship $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ boils it down to evaluating $\Gamma(1/2)$.  And would you do that?

Comment: @Dr.MV For this we can evaluate the Gaussian integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt\pi/2$ with [another method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Computation), and then substituting $x = \sqrt{t}$ gives $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \Gamma(1/2)/2$.

Comment: @arkeet Yes, I know that. I just want others to be aware that the evaluation of the integral of interest using the Gamma function requires that one evaluate the Gamma function.

Comment: Yes, that is the point. But if you want to avoid the function, the integral can be reduced to the Gaussian integral more directly by grixor's answer.

Answer (score 4):

*Using a standard probability distribution:*

If you know the Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{G}(\mu,\sigma)$: its pdf is $f_{\mu,\sigma}\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f_{\mu,\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
and you want to compute, for $X\sim\mathcal{G}(0,1)$,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^\infty x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx &= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f_{0,1}(x)dx =  \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} \mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\left( \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2\right) \\&= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\operatorname{Var}X = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\cdot 1
\\&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{align*}$$
where for the first step we used the fact that $x\mapsto x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is an even function (hence the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ and the change of bounds in the integral).

Comment: Clement, how are you my friend.  This is a fine approach.  But it might prompt, of course, one to ask, "how does one calculate the variance (or any moment) of the normal (Gaussian) distribution in terms of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the corresponding density function?"

Comment: Indeed, it **is** circular (and I fully admit it). But assuming the variance and expectation of a Gaussian are known (which only requires to compute the integral once in a lifetime), this allows one to (re)derive such results very cheaply.

Comment: And that is the rationale for my giving a +1, well deservedly!

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
u&=x^2/2
\\
\mathrm{d}u&=x\mathrm{d}x
\\
\int x^2e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int \frac{x^2e^{-u}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}u
\\&=\int \sqrt{2u}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u
\\&=\sqrt{2}\int u^{1/2}e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u
\\\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\sqrt{2}\:\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+1 \right)*
\\&=\sqrt{2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\\&\quad \text{* where $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function $\int_0^\infty u^{z-1}e^u\mathrm{d}u$}
\end{align}$$

Comment: And how does one evaluate the Gamma function at half integers?  Using the functional relationship $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ boils it down to evaluating $\Gamma(1/2)$.  And would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step note that 
$$
I=\int x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx
$$
can be integrated with the substitution
$$
-\frac{x^2}{2}=t \quad \rightarrow \quad xdx=-dt
$$
and we have:
$$
I=-\int e^t dt = -e^t+C=-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+C
$$

now you can write your integral as:
$$
J=\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2/2}dx=\int_0^{\infty} x d\left(-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \right)
$$

and, integrating by part:
$$
J=\left[-xe^{-x^2/2}\right]_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}dx
$$

The first part is obviously $=0$. For the second, using the definition of the [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), we have:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}dx=\left[\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mbox{erf}(x/\sqrt{2})\right] _0^{\infty}
$$

and, since $\mbox{erf}(0)=0$ and $\lim _{x\to \infty}\mbox{erf}(x)=1$ we have $J=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.